# c3.js grafico area apilado con valores negativos

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Estoy haciendo un gráfico de área apilado con c3.js, pero el gráfico no se ve bien cuando se utilizan valores negativos.

Ejemplo (También disponible en [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hG2eZ/29/)):

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 300, 50, 300, 0, 0, 120],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
            ['data3', 230, -200, 50, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'area-spline',
            data2: 'area-spline',
            data3: 'area-spline'
            // 'line', 'spline', 'step', 'area', 'area-step' are also available to stack
        },
        groups: [['data1', 'data2','data3']]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Un área nunca puede ser negativa. Por tanto, un gráfico de tipo *area-spline* no es un buen tipo de gráfico para representar tus datos.

Piensa mejor como quieres representar tus datos y elige el tipo de gráfico apropiado.